# ATMEL 169PA resets with MCUSR = 0

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega

On rare occasions, my [ATMega169PA](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8018.pdf) resets with MCUSR=0. What can cause this?

I have multiple units (> 500) running the same code and on rare occasions 1 or 2 units will reset with MCUSR=0.

Comment: We'll need a lot more information. How do you know it's restarting? Have you accidentally cleared it before it's read?

Comment: I have an LCD display that flashes and shows the MCUSR value when the unit resets. All other resets such as JTAG, Watchdog, Power On, External and Brown out were individually tested and shown on the display but 1-2 random units display 00 value. Failures occur when the units are placed in a temperature chamber set at -30 deg C for about 5 days.

Comment: I am amazed that you kept the fact of the cold temperature chamber from the original question. This is a critical piece of information that changes the answer.

Comment: This seems like a good question for the site: while more information would be nice, the reality is that the problem in situations such as this is that the engineer on site doesn't know why the behavior is occurring, and is seeking help from those with more experience in investigating such problems.  It's the type of question that's probably going to require some back and forth of ideas in comments to resolve, but that's how engineering is ultimately practiced.

Comment: Did you ever fully resolve this problem? I have a similar issue with an ATMega168PB that _appears_ to be resetting because of some nearby (unintended) RF.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question directly will require a lot more information. How do you know it's restarting? Have you accidentally cleared it before it's read?

Otherwise this would indicate a Power-On-Reset where the voltage drops below VPOT (as specified in the datasheet). I smell a hardware issue somewhere.

[Edit] Given the new information that the unit is being subjected to very cold temperatures. It's almost certain that some units are likely failing because of this. I'd contact Atmel with the failing chip information (lot #, date, etc that are marked on the device) and ask for more guidance. Perhaps a lot had issues. The failure rate seemstoo small to be a PCB issue, but could definitively be explained by some devices not meeting up the -40C spec.

Comment: Failing units are random and not repeatable. I have an LCD display that flashes and shows the MCUSR value when the unit resets. All other resets such as JTAG, Watchdog, Power On, External and Brown out were individually tested and shown on the display but 1-2 random units display 00 value. Failures occur when the units are placed in a temperature chamber set at -30 deg C for about 5 days.

Answer (score 1):

Every now and then I forget to tie the \$\overline{\text{RESET}}\$ pin to Vcc, resulting in random resets. Use a 10k resistor if you want to be able to do in-circuit programming, otherwise you can save the resistor and tie the pin to Vcc directly.

Comment: The reset pin has a 2.2K pull up to Vcc.

Comment: This might explain a random reset, but would it explain an MCUSR (reset cause) value of 0?

Comment: @ChrisStratton nope, but I wanted to have a good reason for using the MathJax markup for overlining as in \$\overline{\text{RESET}}\$

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ATmega169P Datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8018.pdf) the MCUSR register has the following values upon startup:

> • Bit 4 – JTRF: JTAG Reset Flag This bit is set if a reset is being
>   caused by a logic one in the JTAG Reset Register selected by the JTAG
>   instruction AVR_RESET. This bit is reset by a Power-on Reset, or by
>   writing a logic zero to the flag.
>
> • Bit 3 – WDRF: Watchdog Reset Flag This bit is set if a Watchdog
>   Reset occurs. The bit is reset by a Power-on Reset, or by writing a
>   logic zero to the flag.
>
> • Bit 2 – BORF: Brown-out Reset Flag This bit is set if a Brown-out
>   Reset occurs. The bit is reset by a Power-on Reset, or by writing a
>   logic zero to the flag.
>
> • Bit 1 – EXTRF: External Reset Flag This bit is set if an External
>   Reset occurs. The bit is reset by a Power-on Reset, or by writing a
>   logic zero to the flag.
>
> • Bit 0 – PORF: Power-on Reset Flag This bit is set if a Power-on
>   Reset occurs. The bit is reset only by writing a logic zero to the
>   flag.

In the case of a power supply glitch I'd expect the register to contain a value of one, or if the external reset pin was not tied high securely I'd expect a value of two. If you (or the compiler in question) are using the recommendation of reading and resetting the register closely after startup I suspect the microcontroller isn't resetting at all.

A more likely cause is a code error causing code execution to revert back to either the reset vector or a point in the code that makes it appear as though a reboot has occurred. The reset vector is located at program address zero so any jump to that address may cause that problem, but without seeing the code it's difficult to determine. Maybe it's an edge case in the sequence of code and/or interrupt sequences that tends to occur very infrequently, or it may depend on the usage patterns of the devices that exhibit the problem.

Also as suggested by jippie depending on the compiler, the last instruction after main(); is either a rjmp .-2 or a jmp 0x0000 so if the program manages to leave main(); then the controller may show similar behaviour.

Comment: I'm using the GCC compiler. I was hoping that the problem is a code error but with > 500 units running in the same environment and conditions, I should be seeing this failure in more units than 1-2 random units. These failures are not repeatable which makes it harder to debug.

Comment: Infrequent behavior can (amongst other possibilities) be caused either by faulty paths in the program which get triggered only by unusual situations (timing relationships, external inputs, electrical behavior) or by electrical noise/faults disturbing proper operation of the processor.  Consider setting a trap by filling unused memory with jumps to some code which will leave evidence of a runaway (set some other value, go into a loop outputing a character on the UART, whatever).